# Display the name of the columns and rows as coordinates using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi guys i just want to ask how can i show the row and  column names of my table that is somewhat like in excel? This is my sample code below that I've found in Internet but it's not working. Thanks :)

```
function createCell(cell, text, style) {
    var column_num = parseInt( $(this).index() );
    var row_num = parseInt( $(this).parent().index() );
    var div = document.createElement('div'), // create DIV element
        txt = document.createTextNode(text); // create text node
    div.appendChild(txt);                    // append text node to the DIV
    div.setAttribute('class', style);        // set DIV class attribute
    div.setAttribute('row_num','column_num',style);    // set DIV class attribute for IE (?!)
    cell.appendChild(div);                   // append DIV to the table cell
    cell.setAttribute('row_num', 'column_num');
}
```

Code for adding new rows

```
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add row" onclick="Javascript:appendRow()">
    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add column" onclick="Javascript:appendColumn()">



<script type="text/javascript">
// append row to the HTML table
     function appendRow() {
         var tbl = document.getElementById('my-table'), // table reference
             row = tbl.insertRow(tbl.rows.length),      // append table row
             i;
        // insert table cells to the new row
        for (i = 0; i < tbl.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
            createCell(row.insertCell(i), i, 'row');
        }
     }
</script>
```

Click here for [Required Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IMFn.jpg)

Comment: @JacobGeorge How would i do it? Any sample project?

Comment: are you trying to populate a table dynamically and display it? I dont unerstand the core purpose of the code

Comment: @JacobGeorge Yes :) That is really my purpose :)

Comment: Are you ok with jQuery? Or do you wnat to you plain JavaScript?

Comment: @MikayilAbdullayev just plain javascript if possible

Comment: Could you specify in more detail, what is not working with the code - the cells dont display, have wrong indexes, styles, or something else? On thing to check - is the console log in your browser empty (no javasript errors)?

Comment: @MartinStaufcik actually the display but i want to display them as coordinates but can't do it and don't know how. If only you can recommend me some projects about it.

Comment: check the fiddle in my answer for the working code, i cant seem to figure out what was being tried with div.setAttribute('row_num','column_num',style); though

Comment: @JacobGeorge actually i forgot to delete i'm trying to solve it by that. My bad and just a newbie in javascript. I saw it in fiddle. I've comment also how should it be shown :)

Comment: check the updated answer, it has what u need it think

Comment: The setAttribute lines are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to implement the code but I am not sure about the functionality of row_num and column_num in setAttribute for IE

```
$("#test-table tr").each(function() {
    $('td', this).each(function () {
         createCell(this, $(this).parent().index() + ',' + $(this).index(), "red");
     })
})
function createCell(cell, text, style) {
    var column_num = parseInt( $(this).index() );
    var row_num = parseInt( $(this).parent().index() );
    var div = document.createElement('div'), // create DIV element
        txt = document.createTextNode(text); // create text node
    div.appendChild(txt);                    // append text node to the DIV
    div.setAttribute('class', style);        // set DIV class attribute
    div.setAttribute('row_num','column_num',style);    // set DIV class attribute for IE (?!)
    cell.appendChild(div);                   // append DIV to the table cell
    cell.setAttribute('row_num', 'column_num');
}
```

Check the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rf4458dp/2/) for the implementation

Comment: i saw the revisions but can it be as the coordinates of the table? rather than the test words?

Comment: please see image that i've put in your answer. Thanks :)

Comment: it is indeed correct but there is something missing because the ones that are being labeled with coordinates are the ones that is existing because I'm also trying to add rows and columns by having add button. Unfortunately whenever i add columns and rows they are not being labeled.

Comment: when u add a new cell, the function has to be called again. how are you trying to add a cell?

Comment: I'm adding a cell via button.

Comment: i add a cell via clicking a button

Comment: i've put the code where i show the button and how i get a function.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9b8ssg49/3/ here is the link off containing those buttons and my function on how i add a row just don't mind the column but technically it is also like that @JacobGeorge